# Selenium ChromeDriver Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, codeception

I'm using Codeception to run some acceptance tests using WebDriver and a Docker Selenium standalone server. I noticed that after one of my tests threw an error I get this logged:

`[Selenium browser Logs]
  13:59:52.345 SEVERE - https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js - Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED`

Funny thing is that there isn't any google analytics on the page at all (or the app for that matter). I'm guessing that there is some anonymous usage analytics but can't tell whose it is, whether it's [Selenium](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium), [Codeception](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception) or it's included libs, or even the ChromeDriver for Selenium. I run the Selenium server with `--net=host` and maybe that has something to do with it.

Anyone know how to turn these analytics off or let Codeception ignore failed external resources?

Answer (score 1):

add the following entry to your local hosts file,

> 127.0.0.1 www.google-analytics.com
>   127.0.0.1 google-analytics.com
>   127.0.0.1 ssl.google-analytics.com

This works for all browsers, regardless of whether they support plugins. As long as you don't run a web server on your local machine, these connections are instantly rejected and so don't take very long to fail.

You could also try 0.0.0.0 (never personally tested by me though).

> 0.0.0.0 www.google-analytics.com
>   0.0.0.0 google-analytics.com
>   0.0.0.0 ssl.google-analytics.com

PS: 0.0.0.0, a null route, is better. If you're running your own web server you'll start to get 404s if your route to localhost.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have to try this next time it comes up. I can't remember exactly but I stopped running into this error.

Comment: @mfink could it be that you ran it from a different network? I'm currently getting `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` because my tests are waiting for an external JS script. Will try to add it to hosts and see what happens

Comment: @Jezor honestly don't remember, but the issue seemed to resolve itself. It is possible though, now that you mention it, that it could have been my crummy VPN connection.